# Recyclerview: listen to padding click events

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-touch-event

I have an horizontal `RecyclerView` with `leftPadding = 48dp`, `topPadding = 24dp` and `clipToPadding = false`. It starts with an empty space on the left, but when the user scrolls the list its items are drawn on that (previously empty) space. The top space is always empty.

[image]

This `RecyclerView` is inside a FrameLayout with `foreground = selectableItemBackground`.

My problem comes from the fact that the `RecyclerView` consumes and ignores touches on the left and top spaces, meaning an `OnClickListener` won't be triggered, both when attached to the `FrameLayout` or to the `RecyclerView`.

I already tried with `clickable = false` and `focusable = false` on the `RecyclerView`, it doesn't work.

What I'm looking for:

1. Scrollable `RecyclerView`
   [image]
2. Clickable `RecyclerView` items
   [image]
3. `FrameLayout` click events when `RecyclerView's` empty spaces are clicked
4. (alternative to 3) Clickable `RecyclerView's` empty spaces
   [image]
   [image]

EDIT: I've created a simple project that shows the problem I'm talking about: https://github.com/dadino/recyclerviewemptyspacestest
There are 2 commits, on the first one I try to catch the click on the parent view, on the second one I try to catch the click on the RecyclerView itself. Neither of them works.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: What code would you like to see?

Comment: in ur recyclerview adapter, u must have put a global click listner and also the item click listner, make sure u only do that for items. Post code for more details

Comment: Each item's view has it's own clickListener, not the adapter (that is not a View and can't register a clickListener). The problem is not item's click listener, but the clicks not registered outside item's bound (where their clickListeners do not have jurisdiction).

Comment: I've added the link to a simple test project to show my problem.

Comment: This is what I tell nicely constructed question, I'm enjoying reading it.

Comment: Set margin on top to get the click event on `FrameLayout` instead of Padding

Answer (score 14):

You have to create your custom `RecyclerView` implementation, where you would listen to touch events and perform filtering based on that.

```
class MyRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var isValid = false
    private var x: Int = 0
    private var y: Int = 0
    // this will help us to understand whether the event can be considered a touch or scroll
    private val delta: Int = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).scaledTouchSlop

    override fun onTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        val onTouchEvent = super.onTouchEvent(e)
        when (e?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                // saving initial touch location
                x = e.rawX.toInt()
                y = e.rawY.toInt()
                isValid = true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (Math.abs(e.rawX - x) > delta ||
                        Math.abs(e.rawY - y) > delta) {
                    // if a scroll happens - no longer consider this movement as valid
                    // this is needed for handling scroll on the inner part of `RecyclerView`                            
                    isValid = false
                }
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                if (isValid && Math.abs(e.rawX - x) < delta &&
                        Math.abs(e.rawY - y) < delta &&
                        isInRightArea(e)) {
                    // 1. if the movement is still valid
                    // 2. we have actually performed a click                            
                    // 3. the click is in expected rectangle
                    // then perform click
                    performClick()
                }
            }
        }
        return onTouchEvent
    }

    // This is needed in order to handle the edge case, when a click listener 
    // would be fired when performing a click between the items of `RecyclerView`
    private fun isInRightArea(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val r = Rect()
        getGlobalVisibleRect(r)
        r.left = paddingLeft
        r.top = r.top + paddingTop
        return !r.contains(e.rawX.toInt(), e.rawY.toInt())
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]